# Why would you want to overload operators and how can you use its original functionality?

Tags: c++

[image: code errors shown in command line]

I am having trouble trying to understand why someone would want to overload an operator. I understand it can help reassign functionality, but it takes away key functionalities as well.

In an assignment given to me, I was given a skeleton code that `Vector4f` overloaded `=`, and now in `Matrix4f.h`, I can't use `=` when creating a function to turn a matrix into an identity matrix (the matrix is set to a `float`, not `int`).

Is the original functionality lost, or do I need to type cast the `=` somehow? Also, why is even reassigning core functionality operators a good idea? My professor had suggested that we could have done `add()` and overloaded that, but didn't.

Comment: `operator=` should not take away functionality, it extends/adds more functionality.

Comment: thanks, maybe I am misunderstanding the error then, I attached link to the picture of the errors

Comment: Using vectors as an example, it's much easier to understand and reason about something like `v1 = (v2 + v3) / 2;` instead of `v1.set((v2.add(v3)).dividedBy(2));`

Comment: that's what I thought, I just seem to be having a hard time holding original functionality.. In main.cpp, vector.h and matrix.h are imported, but i can't use any basic operators in matrix due to overloading in vector

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] if you're running into problems, showing us what original functionality you're losing.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be with `operator=` but rather `operator*` and `operator[]`, but without enough code to reproduce the error, we'll never know,

Comment: Looking at your error message, the compiler thinks that `this[3][3]` is a `Vector4f`, but presumably it should be an `int&`.  Double-check your `operator[]` for your matrix and vector classes.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots with text in them, but rather the text itself.  Command Prompt has clipboard functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator overloading is a way of adding some syntactic sugar to help your types have a full, semantically-coherent API.

Take, for example, [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). In terms of pure assignment operators, it provides a number of ways to help the string behave in a coherent and semantically-sound way. In addition to the copy/move `operator=` overloads, it supplies:

- `operator=(CharT)`: Assign to a character
- `operator=(const CharT*)`: Assign to a string-literal or pointer to C-style string

Which allow it to behave in a way that the consumer would expect, such as:

```cpp
auto str = std::string{""};
str = "hello world"; // c-style string/string literal
str = 'c';
```

Other operators in this example would be:

- `operator+(const CharT*)`: append c-strings/string literals
- `operator+(CharT)`: append characters
- `operator+(const basic_string&)`: append other `std::string`s
- Equality or comparison operators (`operator==`, `operator<`, etc): comparing things in a coherent way

---

Adding operators doesn't remove functionality. It helps to extend the functionality by providing a semantically clear way of writing code.

**Note:** The *assignment* operator is a special case, in that some circumstances may result in the compiler-generated `operator=` to be deleted. However, you can always define it by-hand, or explicitly use the `= default` syntax to re-enable it. For example:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default; // Explicitly ask for the compiler-generated one
};
```

Languages that do not support operators like this may result in having to write code with everything written out. For example:

```cpp
string("hello").append(' ').append("world")
```

instead of simply

```cpp
std::string{"hello"} + ' ' + "world";
```

(these are contrived examples)

---

**Edit:** The answer above focuses more on your immediate question as to why to overload operators. Your error, as seen in your screenshot, appears to be due to a lacking `operator=` overload for assigning an `int` (or some other numerically convertible type, like a `float`) to the `Vector4f` type. Defining a custom operator would enable this.

Comment: thank you, I believe that may be my answer, we had set vector4f = default, which may have overridden the compiler version. As it doesn't recognize integers despite asking for either a Vector4f or int.

Comment: From the comments on the question, and from the screenshot you posted, it appears like what you may be lacking is an `operator=(float)` overload so that you may assign a numeric value to your `vector4f`. However, this answer is more focusing on your original question (pre-edit) regarding why custom operators would be used

Comment: Yes, it would seem that operator= had overwritten the compiler generated one. Could it be the case that other operands such as + - / can be overwritten? As they also have the same issue.

Comment: Oh? Interesting, we were told to try and keep matrices as floats due to error with doubles. So, not having one for float may be another issue!

Comment: The compiler only generates assignment operators (and comparison in C++20, using `operator<=>` and `default`) -- but it will never generate `+`/`-`/etc. These always have to be authored by hand. Even for the assignment operators, it will only generate ones for copying and moving the same type, but anything else has to be hand-written by the author.

Comment: Thank you again, the operator=(float) was indeed the final issue. I am relatively new to coding (2 years) and have python, java, and c, but just started c++ this year, so i thought it was weird that you could overwrite a core functionality from the compiler